# Do the following methods search in hidden cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using Range.Find and Range.Replace and haven't figured out under what circumstances they only search visible cells and under what circumstances they search both visible and hidden cells.

The following is an example that searches visible and hidden cells:

```
r.Replace what:=fw, replacement:=rw, lookat:=xlPart, matchcase:=False
```

The following is an example that searches only visible cells:

```
lastRowOutput = Sheets("Output").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
```

Is there any predictable pattern to when the methods above search only visible cells or both visible and hidden cells?

EDIT: Or rather, it seems like both methods above search both visible and hidden cells, but neither searches for cells that have been hidden by a filter. This confuses me very much. Why do they search ordinary hidden cells but not cells that have been hidden by a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide a row with *AutoFilter,* it will be hidden from **FIND()**
If you hide a row *manually,* it will be hidden from **FIND()**
If you hide a row by setting its *height to zero,* it will be visible to **FIND()**

Comment: Thank you! Is the same true for replace?

Comment: I think that formulas in manually hidden rows are still searchable, but not in rows that are hidden by filters.

Comment: you cannot replace what you cannot find.

Comment: Makes sense, your sentence echoes of old wisdom.